# Angular 2 Service Data Binding

Tags: angular, angular2-services

When my app first launches I want the `player.service` to make an HTTP request and save the data as a variable in my service for my component(s) to access. My service makes the request just fine and the data does save, but my view never updates.

In my `playerlist.component` I inject the service to have access to the variable but I can't get the data. I imagine it's because I need to do all this observable stuff to make it happen.

All I want is my list in my view to populate when the page loads and have and make sure all my future components have access to a single source of data to prevent multiple http requests.

In my `app.component` I did include `player.service` and put it in the providers...if that matters.

**player.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class PlayerListService {

    public playerListData;

    constructor(private http:Http) {
        this.getPlayerData().subscribe(
            data => this.playerListData = data
        );
    }

    getPlayerData = ():Observable<any> => {
      return this.http.get('my-api').map(response => response.json())
    }
}
```

**playerlist-component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PlayerListService } from '../shared/index';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-player-list',
    templateUrl: './player-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./player-list.component.scss']
})
export class PlayerListComponent implements OnInit {

    public playerList;

    constructor(private playerListService:PlayerListService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.playerList = this.playerListService.playerListData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your data isn't fetched yet when the components's OnInit runs.

What you could do is returning an Observable of your `playerListData` and subscribe to that Observable to get the actual value.

**service**

```
public playerListData: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

constructor(private http:Http) {
    this.getPlayerData().subscribe(
        data => this.playerListData.next(data)
    );
}
```

**component**

In your component you could either just use the `async` pipe in your template

```
{{ playerListService.playerListData | async }}
```

or

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.playerListService.playerListData
        .subscribe(data => this.playerList = data);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I'm getting an error: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.` I put a `console.log()` right after the next(data) and I can see my data, so I'm guessing the problem is in the component `.subscribe()`?

Comment: I just commented out the `.subscribe()` and I don't get an error. So the problem may be there.

Comment: I don't know the structure of the data that comes from the http call so I can't help you there. If you use the async pipe you don't need the subscription.

Comment: Just tried the async code in the view and it worked. I'd like to get the code to work in the ngOnInit()

Comment: The data is just a standard json

Comment: With the OnInit method you should just use `{{ playerList }}` in your view.

Answer (score -1):

you got an error here you are not selecting the provider of this service

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-player-list',
templateUrl: './player-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./player-list.component.scss'],
providers: [PlayerListService] //<--- add this line on your component
```

})

Comment: This is the way you go ONLY IF the service is used by ONE component, or if you want to have multiple instances of a service. But in most cases services are used to share data across multiple components and for communication between them. In such a case, the `providers` decleration belongs to a module.